# The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, httpwebrequest

I am trying to send post request, But I am facing issue with 'The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity.' , I had try lot, but no success, 
Anyone can please tel me , what is wrong with my bellow code.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://url.com");
request.Method = "POST";
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer e*******");

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
    {
        mobile_number = "9763641790",
        first_name = "suraj",
        last_name="mahajan"
    });
    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whats wrong with this code , But i tried bellow method, and it works

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://url.com?mobile_number=9763641790&first_name=suraj&last_name=mahajan");
```

I had send data through url.